# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user' during overriding "social-app-auth-django" create_user

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, python-social-auth, django-login

I noticed that the [SAAD](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) fails to associate an existing user with the social-auth logged in user. This is creating multiple users with the same email address. I tried to override this by commenting out in settings.py,

```
# 'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
```

I then made a view to create a user profile. I added this the pipeline,

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
...
'accounts.views.save_profile',
...
)
```

In `accounts.views`,

```
def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    username = ""
    if backend.name == "google-oauth2":
        email = response["emails"][0]["value"]
        existing_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        username = existing_user.username
        password = existing_user.password
        authenticated_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request,authenticated_user) # I need request to login the user
```

The problem here is that I need request to log in the user. The login requires request and authenticated user as parameters. Suppose I add request as a parameter, I get an `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'`.

```
def save_profile(request, backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    username = ""
    if backend.name == "google-oauth2":
        email = response["emails"][0]["value"]
        existing_user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        username = existing_user.username
        password = existing_user.password
        authenticated_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request,authenticated_user)
```

How do I login the user, having known username and password ?

Traceback of the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 50, in wrapper
return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 28, in complete
redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 41, in do_complete
user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 39, in complete
return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 253, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 398, in auth_complete
*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 253, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 409, in do_auth
return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_django/strategy.py", line 115, in authenticate
return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 74, in authenticate
user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 79, in authenticate
return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 82, in pipeline
out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 107, in run_pipeline
result = func(*args, **out) or {}
  File "/Users/swaggerjeevan07/Desktop/django/mysite/accounts/views.py", line 76, in save_profile
login(request,authenticated_user)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 97, in login
user = request.user     # This is the issue 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was add `social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email`to the pipeline above `create_user`. Now, it checks if there is an account already linked with the obtained social-auth email. If it does't, it creates a new user.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    ...
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'accounts.views.save_profile',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    ...
)
```

The `def save_profile` looks like :

```
def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == "google-oauth2":
        # A dot in username will have url issues 
        username = user.username.replace(".","_") 
        user.username = username
        user.first_name = user.first_name.capitalize()
        user.last_name = user.last_name.capitalize()
```